# jQuery Append only works in debug in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using SignalR for Chat in my app.  When a user connects, I use `.append` to add the users name to a div with a list of users.  The code works fine in Chrome and Edge, but when I run it in FireFox the append does not work unless I hit F12 and run the code in debug mode.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initLoad = true;
    loadRequests();
    @Html.Raw(tabstr)
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        registerEvents(chatHub)
    });
    registerClientMethods(chatHub);
});

    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {
        chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (connectionId, name, jobtitle) {
            AddUser(chatHub, connectionId, name, jobtitle);
        }
    }
    function AddUser(chatHub, connectionId, name, jobtitle) {

    var userId = $('#hdId').val();
    const connectionID = connectionId;
    const userName = name;
    const jobTitle = jobtitle;

   const connectedUser = $("#divusers").append('<div id="' + connectionID + '" class="kt-widget__item" style="cursor:pointer"><div class="kt-widget__info"><div class="kt-widget__section"><a class="kt-widget__username">' + userName + '</a><span class="kt-badge kt-badge--success kt-badge--dot"></span></div>' + jobTitle + '</div></div>');
    connectedUser.on("click", function () {
    var groupWindows = [];
    $('#groupWindowList').empty();

    $('div[id^="ctr"]').each(function () { groupWindows.push(this.id); })

    $.each(groupWindows, function (index, value) {
        var controlname = value;
        const groupName = controlname.replace("ctr", "")
        const listItem = $(`<li>${groupName}</li>`);
        listItem.on("click", function () {
            $('#addToGroupModal').modal('toggle');
            chatHub.server.addUserToGroup(groupName, connectionID);
        });
        $('#groupWindowList').append(listItem);
            })
        $('#addToGroupModal').modal({});
    });

}
```

`const connectedUser + $("#divusers").append` is the problem.  In debug, it is fine, but if I just run the code, the append does not take place and user's name does not display in the list.

Here is my html:

```
  <div class="kt-portlet__body">
       <div class="kt-widget kt-widget--users kt-mt-20">
             <div class="kt-scroll kt-scroll--pull">
                <div id="divusers" class="kt-widget__items">
                 </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> UPDATE
> So I added:

```
    var myElement = $('#divusers')[0];
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
       if (document.contains(myElement)) {
           alert('hi');
                   
    });

observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});
```

to check if the element exists in the DOM.  I replaced the `alert('hi')` with the code to start the ChatHub and the append still does not work.

Another weird thing is if I make almost ANY change in the html and run it.  It works the first time, but if I stop it and run it again.  It doesn't work.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then there's no element with the id `divusers` in the DOM when `AddUser()` is called -> [mcve]

Comment: It is there.  I thought that was a given.  People complain when you add more code than is necessary.  Or are you saying that the html is not rendered?  I have the initial code placed in $(document).ready

Comment: _"It is there"_ - That's what you say, but we cannot reproduce it without a [mcve]. Also the classes on those now added DOM elements look like they are from an unnamed library. Who knows what this thing is doing with the DOM. Add some `console.log()`s (e.g. `console.log($("#divusers").length)`), step through the code with the debugger, ...

Comment: @Andreas - divusers does have length, but that is when debugging, and it works fine when debugging.  And just in case the classes were the issue, I removed the classes from the divs and it still doesn't work.  Weird thing is it works "sometimes".  If I stop and start the app a few times, the append may happen every 5th time or so.  I have never used FireFox and was just testing for multi-browser functionality, but we cannot force our users to only use Chrome or Edge so I have to get this figured out.

Comment: So is "#divusers" dynamcially added by something else??

Comment: @epascarello - no.  It is already in the existing html, that is why I can't make sense of it.  It is already there, and the function is called from document.ready